# I need assistance on reusing an ID more than once

Tags: javascript

So I am making a word guessing game,

[image]

On my Game.js file I have a class called Game that has a method called `checkForwin()` that checks if a player has selected all letters in the game, it works based on the `console.log` messages I see

```
checkForWin() {
    //phraseMatch is the length of the empty boxes
const phraseMatch  = $('.letter').length;
//match is the length of the displayed boxes with the class of show
const match  = $('.letter.show').length;
//if the length of the empty boxes is equal to the length of the displayed boxes then return true
  if (phraseMatch === match) {
      console.log(phraseMatch + match + ' (the player has chosen all letters in the phrase')
    return true
  }

}
```

where I am stuck on though is on a method called `gameOver()`, this method will display either a red screen if a player loses or a green screen if a player wins, 
I am able to select a `h1` with the ID of `#game-over-message` in order to change the message and color of screen by adding the class ('lose a') when the player loses, but when I try to use that same id a second time by saying

```
else if (this.checkForWin === true || this.missed < 5)  {
        $('#game-over-message').text('You won!');
        $('#overlay').show().addClass('win a');
        $('#btn__reset').text('Try Again!');



    }
```

I can't seem to access the id in order to display the winning color by adding the class ('win a') that I have on my css file

```
gameOver() {
    //if the player misses 5 times, display the game over message from index.html
    if (this.missed === 5) {
        $('#game-over-message').text('Game Over You Lost'); 
        $('#overlay').show().addClass('lose a');
        $('#btn__reset').text('Try Again!!');






    } else if (this.checkForWin === true || this.missed < 5)  {
        $('#game-over-message').text('You won!');
        $('#overlay').show().addClass('win a');
        $('#btn__reset').text('Try Again!');



    }

}
```

Could someone please help? this is my repo for reference https://github.com/SpaceXar20/FSJS-techdegree-project-4-b

Comment: `'win a'` are two seperate classes

Comment: I have something similar, when I use $('#overlay').show().addClass('lose a'), that seems to be working fine , just not when I use $('#overlay').show().addClass('win a');, could you please elaborate your answer

Comment: i dont quite understand your problem, `I can't seem to access the id in order to display the winning color by adding the class ('win a')` - how you seem this?

Comment: Ah yes allow me to clarify , on my html file I have this h1: `<h1 id="game-over-message"></h1>`, this is the id I am referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. the reason you don't get the output is you have called the game over function only when you miss the 5 chances. call the gameOver() on the handleInteraction like below and you will get the output.  I also noticed that there is not point having the game over function you can simply call do winning css change at the point you have put the console log saying "the player has chosen all letters in the phrase" and the red css change inside the removeLife() where you have have called the gameOver();

```
handleInteraction(letter) {

    /*if the player matched a letter, the checkforwin method will be called
    and the letter will be shown by calling showedMatchedLetter()
    */
    if (phrase.checkLetter(letter) === true) {

        phrase.showMatchedLetter(letter);
        this.checkForWin();

    } //if the player didn't match a letter, the game will remove a heart life by calling removelife method and add 1 to the missed property
      else {
          this.removeLife();

      }

      this.gameOver();

}
```

Hope you got your answer :)

Comment: You're right!, I spent a lot of time focusing on the if statement that I overlooked the **handleInteraction()**, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

i guess your `else if` condition never matched

instead of

`this.checkForWin === true` (which is always false as it is a function)

you want to check the actual return value so you have to execute it

`this.checkForWin() === true`

you could have found out  yourself that it did not execute by using for example `console.log("xyz")` for debugging